# Is there anything similar to "Add Service Reference" in Xcode?

Tags: visual-studio, xcode

My current place of employment is primarily a Microsoft shop and we use Visual Studio pretty extensively. I've grown fond of the laziness of using "Add Service Reference" (formerly "Add Web Reference" in VS2005) to download WSDLs and form classes and methods in nice, convenient namespaces for me.

Since we have started to branch out into iPhone development, we have been using Xcode as our IDE for iPhone projects. I would like to be able to do something similar, but haven't been able to find if this ability exists.

If there is similar functionality in Xcode, where is it?
If not, is there a template or something I can download that will do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not anything built in for consuming soap services.  If your team is using WCF for the web-service your easiest route is going to be adding a REST endpoint to your existing service.  Then you can use a combination of NSUrlConnection, NSXmlParser and key-value coding to make it almost as easy.

Comment: I'm giving an upvote for answering the first part. That there isn't an equivalent. Assume I have no control over the endpoints, pure consumer on my end (for example I was using Amazon's services).

Comment: I havent seen anything easy for implementing soap...  However if you really are using Amazon services, not only is there a REST api already, but someone has written iPhone code and uploaded it to their developer site.

Comment: Not using Amazon, just throwing it out as an example of an API I have no control over and can't change it to REST even if it didn't already have one. Anyway, I've searched for a few days and it looks like I'll be rolling my own.